# Create <md-switch> with icon in angular-material

Tags: css, angular-material

How can I create this md-switch with icon?

I took example from [www.inbox.google.com](http://www.inbox.google.com)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `background-image` to the `.md-thumb` class

```
.md-thumb{    
  background: url('imageUrl');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Edit:**

Show icon on ON:

```
.md-checked .md-thumb{    
  background: url('imageUrl');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Show icon on OFF:

```
.md-checked .md-thumb{    
  background: none;
}

.md-thumb{    
  background: url('imageUrl');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. for reply
One more thing if I want to toggle that icon on OFF or ON how can I achieve this. ?

Comment: thank you so much. it worked for me. only padding for icon is not coming inside switch as shown in above image. if I am adding padding in .md-thumb the size of circle increasing.

2nd thing the background color I dont want to be change when checked and unchecked.

Comment: You can use `background-position` to center it. Or you use Photoshop to create a perfect circle with icon centered and use that as `background-image`. You can use `background: #000 url('imageUrl')` and `background:#000` for the other one so it will both be black. Don't forget to accept this answer :)